# Opencv MOG and GMG subtractor not working

Tags: python, opencv, mog

i have been going through opencv mog and gmg background subtraction,
i have installed opencv 3.3.0 from

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

and also opencv from the same version,
but still i couldn't find MOG not working, where as mog 2 is working,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()

while(1):
   ret, frame = cap.read()

   fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

   cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break 

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "back.py", line 6, in <module>
    fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not calling the correct function to create the background substractor...

You can follow the [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html) (it is for version 3.0, but I couldn't find it for 3.3, however it is the same) to have a more in depth explanation of how to use it.

As you can see in the link I provided, you have to call

```
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

instead of

```
fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

Then the rest is the same.

Comment: i created mog and also used fgbg.apply..yet i get there is no attribute as BackgroundSubtractorMog()....

Comment: @Arvind it could be that the OpenCV python install is incomplete, I suppose you installed them by sources, are you sure this module was selected?

Comment: yes,because without contrib being installed background subtraction didnt work,but after i instaleed it works,but only mog didnt work,

Answer (score 0):

fgbg = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
didn't work for me too but there is another improved version of background subtraction which works similar
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()